# accessing integer as a list

Tags: c

```
void raiden(unsigned long *data,unsigned long *result,unsigned long *key)
{

unsigned long b0=data[0] , b1=data[1]
```

Trying to understand this, with little success, though. How the unsigned long integer can be accessed as data[something]? I can understand this is data would be a list like {"foo","bar"}, but how this refers to an integer?

Comment: because `a[x]` translates to `*(a + x)`

Comment: because arrays are represented by pointers in C

Comment: You seem to come from a very different programming background than C. Please read on basic information about the C language first.

Answer (score 0):

because `unsigned long *` is not `unsigned long`. it is pointer to some address in memory. For more information I would recommend to read this book   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language